# Image Extraction using python

Tags: python

I'm using using fitz to extract images from a PDF file but the output images aren't in the same order as in the pdf. Is there any method to extract these images in order.
note: every page contains 2 images, and I want to extract the left one first then the right one.

```
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):                                                                                 
if ( page_index < 4 or page_index == len(pdf_file) - 1 ): continue                                                 
# get the page itself
page = pdf_file[page_index]
image_list = page.getImageList()                                                                                

v = 0
for image_index, img in enumerate(page.getImageList(), start=1):
    if v == 0:                                                                                            
        v += 1
        continue
    # get the XREF of the image
    xref = img[0]
    # extract the image bytes
    base_image = pdf_file.extractImage(xref)
    image_bytes = base_image["image"]
    # get the image extension
    image_ext = base_image["ext"]
    # load it to PIL
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
    # save it to local disk
```

Comment: So to differentiate between the right and left images, I should use xref, right?

Comment: I tried to print out the image list and i didn't find the positions, is there any function to be used to get the position?